# SQL Chaining joins

Tags: mysql, join

**EDIT: The isssue was mismatching data the B-ids in tables A_B and B_C had no overlap**

I have the following tables:

- A(id, …)
- A_B(a_id, b_id)
- B_C(b_id, c_id)
- C_D(c_id, d_id)
- D(id, value, …)

Where I want some rows from A based on the value of the row in D.
The tables A_B, B_C and C_D are just id mappings from one table to another.

I was trying to get to something that would look something like this:

```
select * from A where D.value = "true"
```

I got this far:

```
select * from A 
inner join A_B on A_B.a_id = A.id
inner join B_C on B_C.b_id = A_B.b_id
```

which is just an empty table.

I am starting to think that I am approaching this issue in the wrong way or perhaps have misunderstood how one should go about joining tables.

Comment: What you have looks right. Do you have some sample data you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got works OK if your data is coherent.  Here's a version of your database and query which demonstrates that.  For simplicity, I inferred the existence of tables `b` and `c`, and made the various columns in the `X_Y` style tables into foreign keys to the single-letter tables.

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    info    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE b
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE C
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    extra   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE d
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    value   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE a_b
(
    a_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a,
    b_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES b,
    PRIMARY KEY (a_id, b_id)
);
CREATE TABLE b_c
(
    b_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES b,
    c_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES C,
    PRIMARY KEY(b_id, c_id)
);
CREATE TABLE c_d
(
    c_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES C,
    d_id    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES d,
    PRIMARY KEY(c_id, d_id)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1, "Quasimodo");
INSERT INTO b VALUES(20, "Quiet");
INSERT INTO C VALUES(333, "Contemporaneous");
INSERT INTO d VALUES(4444, "true");

INSERT INTO a_b VALUES(1, 20);
INSERT INTO b_c VALUES(20, 333);
INSERT INTO c_d VALUES(333, 4444);
```

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  JOIN a_b ON a_b.a_id = a.id
  JOIN b_c ON b_c.b_id = a_b.b_id
  JOIN c_d ON c_d.c_id = b_c.c_id
  JOIN d   ON d.id     = c_d.d_id
 WHERE d.value = "true";
```

For the given data, that produces:

```
1      Quasimodo     1      20     20     333    333    4444   4444   true
```

So, if the data is correct, the query you were building can produce an answer.  However, if you were getting an empty table on your incomplete query, then there is a data problem in your tables — or (outside chance) your outline schema misled us.

<sup>*Testing performed on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, using Informix 12.10.FC6, but using what is believed to be a subset of SQL common to Informix and MySQL.*</sup>

Comment: After having examined the data, it seems like there was indeed something missing. Thanks for the help!